# How can I make the keyboard go away?

Tags: iphone

I have a app I'm making that has 2 text fields and buttons below it.  When the user starts to type, the keyboard comes up and covers the buttons.  Is there a way to make the keyboard go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do so

// this one line will dismiss the keyboard from anywhere in your code

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

**or**

with the delegate of textfield (you should declare it in your .h file first)

```
@interface someController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

and the in .m

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

   // next line will dismiss the keyboard 
   [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `UITextField` documentation:

```
To dismiss the keyboard, send the resignFirstResponder message to the text field that is currently the first responder. Doing so causes the text field object to end the current editing session (with the delegate object’s consent) and hide the keyboard.
```

In other words, just send `resignFirstResponder` to an active text field object.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:self.alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

In the view controller after setting the text field `delegate` to self.